# Can PHPExcel read a file stream in memory?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have a requirement to read an Excel file that is on sFTP without copying it to the web server. I am successfully reading the file from sFTP and returning the results of stream_get_contents, but PHPExcel doesn't seem to be able to read this stream.

Is it possible to read an Excel file with PHPExcel without copying it to the web server? Are there any other libraries out there that can?

Comment: No it can't; it requires a physical file on on the web server

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, @MarkBaker.